# My motherboard caught on fire. What is this component?

Tags: motherboard

**Simplified:**

What is the name of this red circled thing? Why it got burned when I powered on?

**Detailed:**

I have bought a PC a month ago and it often (1 minute or less) automatically turns off.

Took to the store, they told me it is the "processor". I left the PC there for maintenance and after one month (today) I got the PC back.

When I powered on, went on BIOS, looked at the settings, fixed the clock. Suddenly PC powered off. When I pressed to power on again, I saw a "flame" from the hole of the cooler. I took out of the plug and opened the PC. Some little component was burned and melted (yes). But I don't know what is it. A transistor maybe. You can see what is it on the picture below.

[image: ![](http://s13.postimage.org/mgs098rad/Untitled.jpg)]

So, what is the name? Is it really a transistor? Why did this thing get burnt? Is it possible that everything is gone too?

I guess it is not processor related. The power supply is the LPZ12-50 500W 12V with automatic 110 or 220 voltage detector

The model of the mobo: Intel dh61crbr

**UPDATE:**

Here is the real photo, sorry for the delay, I was waiting for the battery of camera charge.

[image: ![](http://s7.postimage.org/icfywng49/20120714_220709.jpg)]

Comment: Can you take a close-up photo of this component?

Comment: fixed the time and date

Comment: i updated the post with the real photo. can you take a look? thank you

Comment: As you can see, you have two similar components (one above and one below). I bet they're equal and equal to the one that burnt.

Comment: yes, but what they are? do you know the name? why THEY got burnt, and not another component.

Comment: Can you read what is on one of those components? Or post a photo where we can read it?

Comment: The [magic smoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke) escaped.  It the old days you used to be able to take a component to the electronics store and they could re-fill the smoke reservoir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component is too small in the photo, you need to take a close-up photo to be certain. The only other photos I could find with [Google Images](http://images.google.com/images?q=dh61crbr) were these two: [[1]](http://conteudo.efacil.com.br/p/23/400/2304607_01.jpg)[[2]](http://www.atera.com.br/IMGAdic/DH61CRBR.3.jpg)

But, it is likely a [voltage-regulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_regulator) (figure 1). A voltage regulator does what its name suggests: it regulates the voltage so that it is regular and steady (which electronic components need). As such, it is susceptible to failure due to spikes and wear-and-tear.

I had an ASUS P4P800 that worked fine, then one day I turned it on and smelled burned electronics. The voltage-regulator on my board had burned and the plastic blistered and bubbled! (figure 2) I had to replace the motherboard, but the CPU, RAM and everything were okay (thankfully). It is also sort of like a fuse, so it *should* protect the rest of the system from burning out.

[image: Voltage regulator]

[image: Burned voltage regulator]

Comment: I've found in the technical docs for this board that, in the picture, the area to the top and right of the processor is the voltage regulation area. Synetech is on the right track.

Comment: Yeah, it's either one of the MOS switches or one of the inductors. Likely, the capacitors failed first and that caused the regulator to overload trying to compensate. Short answer: replace the motherboard.

Comment: i updated the post with the real photo. can you take a look? thank you

Comment: @Stew, you can get the part-number from the other ones beside it to be sure exactly what it is (I think I can see a “640” on the top one), but yes, it looks like a voltage-regulator. Like David said, it could be one of the capacitors that failed (unfortunately too common with motherboards), but it doesn’t look like one of the ones in the photo.

Comment: but the motherboard are brand new. this is sad. :( if it is the voltage regulator, maybe this happened because of the power supply or anything related?

Comment: @Stew, it could be a bad power supply. Check the ATX connector for signs of [burning](http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2064/1983844631_52bacf38af_z.jpg) (they may be light-brown). If the motherboard is new, then you should be able to exchange it. If you bought it at a store, bring it back and complain that a component on the board failed; if you bought it online, get an RMA.

Comment: the atx connector is totally normal. i can't excange or complain because that "month" i was talking about is that i bought the CPU on the other side of the country. shipping to the store and them shipping back took 1 month. i dont want to wait another month to a chance of another accident. i rather buy another on my city. i am afraid of instead of buying only the mobo, will have to buy another atx or processor. ;( i only will know that monday.

Comment: @Stew, one thing you can try is to [contact Intel](http://www.intel.com/cd/corporate/feedback/apac/eng/250943.htm) to explain that their board failed. They may offer to replace it for your or even even give you a credit or refund. I had an EPoX motherboard that died after the warranty expired and they offered to do a “courtesy repair”, but sent me a replacement. Don’t get your hopes up with Intel though; I bought a QX3 microscope for $72CAD and it soon died. I begged and pleaded with them, but all they did was to give me a $24CAD refund after making me spend $30 to ship it back to them in USA.

Comment: @Stew: It could be caused by a CPU or power supply problem, but that's pretty rare. Usually, this is a pure motherboard failure. It can be caused by improper motherboard handling causing a component to be damaged or improper mounting causing a short. But most likely, the motherboard was just bad.

Comment: Yup, you may simply be a victim of [capacitor plague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague).